# Instrumentation Agent not hooking up to the app

Tags: java, instrumentation

My Agent Class

```
package com.mytransformers;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class MyTransformerAgent {

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        MyTransformer transformer = new MyTransformer();
        inst.addTransformer(transformer);
    }

}
```

My Transformer:

```
public class MyTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer{

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader arg0, String arg1, Class<?> arg2, ProtectionDomain arg3, byte[] arg4)
            throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        // processing to return some bytes/null;
    }
```

I built my manifest using maven POM and I can confirm that my jar has the following manifest inside META-INF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.mytransformers.MyTransformerAgent
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ha9u63@r
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Class-Path: C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix: true
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_141
Boot-Class-Path: C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
```

I copy both my application jar (simple Hello World 1 line statement) and the agent jar into the same folder and run the following:

`java -javaagent:myagent.jar -jar myapp.jar`

And I am constantly getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mytransformers.MyTransformerAgent
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

What else is missing here? I am a bit confused. Is there some classloading delegation which I have broken?

Regards,

Comment: Did you verify that the agent class is in the jar file, within the correct directory? And does your transformer truly have dependencies to tomcat?

Comment: Yes it has and the class is there I verified using javap 

I even tried using no package i.e. thr plain classes in the jar. No luck

Comment: Try a run with Java 9. iirc, it provides more detailed information when a class lookup failed due to other dependencies, so maybe you get useful information from that test.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... looks like java says that it cannot find class `com.mytransformers.MyTransformerAgent` in `C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar` according your manifest =)

Maybe to add your jar to `Boot-Class-Path` list like:
`Boot-Class-Path: C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.16/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar myagent.jar`